# What does the symbol @ mean in Puppet output after applying a catalog

Tags: puppet, catalog, puppet-enterprise

I am applying a catalog in a machine and in the first run it returns the following output (just a part).

I understand that lines that begin with the less symbol were removed and the ones that start with the plus symbol were added, but what does the @ mean?

```
-#  /etc/rsyslog.conf   Configuration file for rsyslog.
+#  /etc/rsyslog.conf   Configuration file for rsyslog v3.
 #
-#          For more information see
+#          For more information see 
 #          /usr/share/doc/rsyslog-doc/html/rsyslog_conf.html


@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
 #################

 $ModLoad imuxsock # provides support for local system logging
-$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support
+$ModLoad imklog   # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd) 
 #$ModLoad immark  # provides --MARK-- message capability

 # provides UDP syslog reception
@@ -38,12 +38,6 @@
 $FileGroup adm
 $FileCreateMode 0640
 $DirCreateMode 0755
-$Umask 0022
-
-#
-# Where to place spool and state files
-#
-$WorkDirectory /var/spool/rsyslog

 #
 # Include all config files in /etc/rsyslog.d/
@@ -58,6 +52,8 @@
```

Obs: I have etckeeper running in this machine. Is possible that it is related somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The @@ .. @@ headers are (c)hunk headers and provide range information.

Details here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Unified_format

The format is:

```
@@ -l,s +l,s @@


l : starting line number

s : number of lines the change applies to

- : original file

+ : modified or new file
```

This is the same syntax as you see in git diff.